# How to speed up a symbolic integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have a question about an integral. I wanna integrate this:

```
-((cA Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1])/(-1 + x)) + (
cA Log[-(sa1/(-mgl^2 - sa1))])/(1 - x) + (cA cF Log[-1 + 1/x])/(
1 - x) - (2 cF^2 Log[-1 + 1/x])/(1 - x) + (2 cF Log[1 - x])/(
1 - x) + 1/
2 cA (2/(-1 + x) + sa1^2/(
2 mgl^4 + 4 mgl^2 sa1 + 2 sa1^2 - 4 mgl^2 sa1 x - 4 sa1^2 x + 
 2 sa1^2 x^2) - (sa1^2 x)/(
 2 mgl^4 + 4 mgl^2 sa1 + 2 sa1^2 - 4 mgl^2 sa1 x - 4 sa1^2 x + 
 2 sa1^2 x^2) + (2 Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x])/(-1 + x))
```

over `x` from `0` to `z`. Every part in the integral is real. When I do this:

`Integrate[Kqq1P, {x, 0, z}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < z < 1, x \[Element] Real, Kqq1P \[Element] Real}]`

It seems to take years. Does anyone know how to speed up that integration. By the way Kqq1P is that expression above.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Marcel

Comment: There are a number of parameters and telling it that the entire expression is real (which is done incorrectly above, should use `Reals` where you have `Real`) is not sufficient to unravel possible branch cut crossings. This is an issue for the subexpression `Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x]`.

Answer (score 9):

The "trick" which works frequently when Mathematica refuses to calculate a definite integral is to calculate first the indefinite integral, then take the limits at the ends of the integration interval and subtract the results.

Here we go.

Let the integrand be

```
f = -((cA Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1])/(-1 + x)) + (cA Log[-(sa1/(-mgl^2 - sa1))])/(1 - x) + (cA cF Log[-1 + 1/x])/(1 - x) - (2 cF^2 Log[-1 + 1/x])/(1 - 
     x) + (2 cF Log[1 - x])/(1 - x) + 
  1/2 cA (2/(-1 + x) + 
     sa1^2/(2 mgl^4 + 4 mgl^2 sa1 + 2 sa1^2 - 4 mgl^2 sa1 x - 4 sa1^2 x + 
        2 sa1^2 x^2) - (sa1^2 x)/(2 mgl^4 + 4 mgl^2 sa1 + 2 sa1^2 - 
        4 mgl^2 sa1 x - 4 sa1^2 x + 
        2 sa1^2 x^2) + (2 Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x])/(-1 + x));
```

Now take the indefinte integral

```
f1 = Integrate[f, x]

(*
Out[6]= (cA mgl^2)/(4 (-mgl^2 - sa1 + sa1 x)) + cA Log[1 - x] - 
 cA Log[sa1/(mgl^2 + sa1)] Log[1 - x] - cA Log[(mgl^2 + sa1)/sa1] Log[1 - x] -
  cF Log[1 - x]^2 - 1/2 cA cF Log[-1 + x]^2 + cF^2 Log[-1 + x]^2 - 
 cA cF Log[-1 + x] (Log[-1 + 1/x] - Log[-1 + x] + Log[x]) + 
 2 cF^2 Log[-1 + x] (Log[-1 + 1/x] - Log[-1 + x] + Log[x]) - 
 1/4 cA Log[mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 x] - cA cF PolyLog[2, 1 - x] + 
 2 cF^2 PolyLog[2, 1 - x] + 
 cA (Log[1 - (sa1 (1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x))/mgl^2] Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x] + 
    PolyLog[2, (sa1 (1 + mgl^2/sa1 - x))/mgl^2])
*)
```

Calculate the limit at the lower end of the interval

```
fi0 = Limit[f1, x -> 0]

(*
Out[23]= -(2/3) cA cF \[Pi]^2 + (4 cF^2 \[Pi]^2)/3 - (cA mgl^2)/(4 (mgl^2 + sa1)) - 
 1/4 cA Log[mgl^2 + sa1] + cA Log[-(sa1/mgl^2)] Log[(mgl^2 + sa1)/sa1] + 
 cA PolyLog[2, 1 + sa1/mgl^2]
*)
```

and similarly for the limit at the upper end of the interval

```
fi1 = Limit[f1, x -> z]

(*
Out[24]= -((cA mgl^2)/(4 (mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 z))) + cA Log[1 - z] - 
 cA Log[sa1/mgl^2] Log[1 - z] - cA Log[(mgl^2 + sa1)/sa1] Log[1 - z] + 
 cA Log[1 + sa1/mgl^2] Log[1 - z] - cF Log[1 - z]^2 - 
 cA cF Log[-1 + 1/z] Log[-1 + z] + 2 cF^2 Log[-1 + 1/z] Log[-1 + z] + 
 1/2 cA cF Log[-1 + z]^2 - cF^2 Log[-1 + z]^2 + 
 cA Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - z] Log[(sa1 (-1 + z))/mgl^2] - 
 cA cF Log[-1 + z] Log[z] + 2 cF^2 Log[-1 + z] Log[z] - 
 1/4 cA Log[mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 z] + cF (-cA + 2 cF) PolyLog[2, 1 - z] + 
 cA PolyLog[2, (mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 z)/mgl^2]
*)
```

The difference should be the value of the definite integral:

```
fd = fi1 - fi0 // Simplify

(*
Out[25]= 2/3 cA cF \[Pi]^2 - (4 cF^2 \[Pi]^2)/3 + (cA mgl^2)/(4 (mgl^2 + sa1)) - (
 cA mgl^2)/(4 (mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 z)) + 1/4 cA Log[mgl^2 + sa1] - 
 cA Log[-(sa1/mgl^2)] Log[(mgl^2 + sa1)/sa1] + cA Log[1 - z] - 
 cA Log[sa1/mgl^2] Log[1 - z] - cA Log[(mgl^2 + sa1)/sa1] Log[1 - z] + 
 cA Log[1 + sa1/mgl^2] Log[1 - z] - cF Log[1 - z]^2 - 
 cA cF Log[-1 + 1/z] Log[-1 + z] + 2 cF^2 Log[-1 + 1/z] Log[-1 + z] + 
 1/2 cA cF Log[-1 + z]^2 - cF^2 Log[-1 + z]^2 + 
 cA Log[1 + mgl^2/sa1 - z] Log[(sa1 (-1 + z))/mgl^2] - 
 cA cF Log[-1 + z] Log[z] + 2 cF^2 Log[-1 + z] Log[z] - 
 1/4 cA Log[mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 z] - cA PolyLog[2, 1 + sa1/mgl^2] + 
 cF (-cA + 2 cF) PolyLog[2, 1 - z] + 
 cA PolyLog[2, (mgl^2 + sa1 - sa1 z)/mgl^2]
*)
```

All these calculations are done by MMA in almost no time.

It should be mentioned that, stricly speaking, we should check if the indefinite integral is a continuous function of x. If not, the result obatined may be wrong. But continuity depends of the parameters of the problem, and therefore is not easily checked.

Comment: helped. Thanks. But why is that faster?

Comment: @Marcel: I can't say because I don't know the details of the very complicated and comprehensive internal code of Integrate[]. Finding the indefinite integral (a so called antiderivative) is a fairly quick procedure while the next step, the limits, can take much longer, and the continuity check (which we skipped here) even longer.

Comment: As a sanity check, one could compare the results from the numerical evaluation of the closed form with the corresponding result from `NIntegrate[]`.

Comment: @J. M.: yes, this is a good idea. To justify a posteriori not having done the complicated analyses.